Android: Fragment changes when I change to dark theme
I have an activity that uses bottom navigation for fragments and an options menu to choose the theme. The problem is when I change the theme the fragment changes as well to the first one, not the one that I am curently on.
This is the code where I change the theme:
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.light_mode -> {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
                sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("AppPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                val editor = sharedPrefs.edit()
                editor.putBoolean(THEME_PREF_KEY, false)
                editor.apply()
                true
            }
            R.id.dark_mode -> {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
                sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("AppPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                val editor = sharedPrefs.edit()
                editor.putBoolean(THEME_PREF_KEY, true)
                editor.apply()
                true
            }
            R.id.log_out -> {
                logout()
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }


You'll want to look into saving & restoring your view state when a configuration change happens.

For an Activity...

Save view state: onSaveInstanceState
Restore view state: Either onCreate or onRestoreInstanceState

For a Fragment...

Save view state: onSaveInstanceState
Restore view state: Either onCreate or onCreateView or onViewCreated

Links:

API reference for Activity onSaveInstanceState
API reference for Fragment onSaveInstanceState


But isn't that just when the fragment restarts, not the activity?

@Alex I didn't realize I linked to fragment documentation, my mistake! However, the same principle applies. When an Activity or Fragment gets re-created, you are responsible for saving and restoring the view state and onSaveInstanceState/onRestoreInstanceState is how you can handle that. I will update my answer with the correct link.
